# ASP .net MVC How to retrieve kendo combobox control value in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui

I want selected dropdown (which is in view) value in a controller to do some logic. How can I get kendo combobox value into the controller? I tried using `FormCollection` but was getting null value for the dropdown even though it is selected. I also tried `request.form["name"]` but it that failed to work.

Index page control

```
var xyz= Model.ListValues.XYZ;
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.XyzId)
@Html.ComboBoxKendoFor(m => m.Id, "", comboStyle, xyz, "Select")
```

ComboBoxKendoFor returning me this

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlHelper.Kendo()
                .ComboBoxFor(expression)
                .Name("KendoCombobox")
                .BindTo(dropDownDataSource)
                .Placeholder(placeHolder)
                .DataTextField("Text")
                .DataValueField("Value")
                .HtmlAttributes(internalhtmlAttributes)
                .ToHtmlString());
```

This is working fine and setting value properly in dropdown.
Now I have an `autocompleteTextbox`. When the user enters text there to search, it displays results for selection. How can I filter this result based on above combobox value in a controller?

Here is my search function in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(FormCollection form)
{
    var dpVal = form["KendoCombobox"];
    string a = Request.Form["Id"];
    string a2 = Request.Form["KendoCombobox"];
    var result = //ServiceCall here
    return Json(result.Value.ToViewModel());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the KendoCombobox is in the formCollection you send to the server?

Comment: Yes...it is in html.beginform ()